# What's the recommended way to include vendor library dependencies in your plugins?

Tags: plugin-development, config

My plugin requires vendor library dependencies and api keys set. What is the recommended way to register an external library? I would also like to configure the public api keys separately for stage and production environments — is there a way to set these in craft/config with the rest of the multi-environment configuration? Or is it better to create a plugin config file of some kind?

Currently I am having to include these in each of my service methods (and something similar again in my javascript files):

```
private function _saveStripeCustomer($account, $token = NULL)
{
    require_once(CRAFT_PLUGINS_PATH . 'businesslogic/vendor/stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
    \Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    // ...
}
```

I'm not familiar with composer. I don't know if that can perhaps help here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Composer!

There's already a package for Stripe: https://packagist.org/packages/stripe/stripe-php

1. Install [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-nix).
2. Add a `composer.json` file in your plugin's root folder.
3. Add this to the `composer.json` file:

   `{
       "require": {
           "stripe/stripe-php": "1.17.2"
       }
   }`
4. Run `php composer.phar update` from your plugin's root folder.
5. The library will be installed in a `/vendor` folder in your plugin.
6. Add an `init()` method to your main plugin's class file with this in it:

   `require CRAFT_PLUGINS_PATH.'/pluginhandle/vendor/autoload.php';`

And you're done.

Composer will handle autoloading all of the class files, so you don't need to worry about it.

If you ever want to update the Stripe library to a newer release, grab the version number from the packagist site, update your `composer.json` file with it and run `php composer.phar update` again.

Comment: Thanks! You're the master. One problem getting this reply in console: `Could not open input file: composer.phar` I tried using sudo as well.

Comment: Hold on. Missing step 1. ;)

Comment: Got it. Thanks. That's great! So, regarding multi-environment config for API key?

Comment: Oh, didn't even read that part.  Probably better to edit this to have the "dependency" question and add a new one for the API key.